# Answer deleted by a moderator, can't tell why

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

[Bind a function to String.prototype so it's always bound to the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733804/bind-a-function-to-string-prototype-so-its-always-bound-to-the-string/22734299#22734299)

Can anyone shed some light on why this was deleted? The solution works perfectly (and even if it didn't, is that valid grounds for deletion?), and I haven't done anything that explicitly violates any rules.

There was no comment on the deletion.

Here is the answer:

---

Try this:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "contains", {
    get: function () {
        return (function(str) {
            return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
        }).bind(this);
    }
});
```

It defines a new property with a getter, meaning every time you "get" the function, for example in `['foo', 'bar'].every(str.contains);`, the function defined above would get called and the return value of that function would be returned as `str.contains`, in this case. The function is the same as yours, only we bind `this` in the getter which is the string, which is what we want.

If `Object.defineProperty` isn't defined in your browser (or anyone to use your code), you can use `__defineGetter__` instead.

A complete solution would look like this:

```
addPropertyWithGetter = function(object, property) {

    getter = function () {
        return (function(str) {
            return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
        }).bind(this);
    }

    if (_.isFunction(Object.defineProperty)) {
        return Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
            get: getter,
        });
    } else {
        object.__defineGetter__(property, getter);
    }
}
```

And the usage:

`addPropertyWithGetter(String.prototype, "contains")`

Comment: My best guess is this was a misclick

Answer (score 9):

It was a copy and paste of another answer of yours. As such that gets automatically flagged by the system because exactly duplicating answers is almost never the right action. If the questions themselves really are duplicates then you should pick just one to answer and flag/comment on the other. If they aren't duplicates then they deserve an individual answer that addresses the specific details of each question, not just a copy and paste.

Since it looks like that doesn't apply to this case in the usual sense I undeleted it.

Comment: It most certainly wasn't!

Comment: @mos Revision 1 was a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22734289/168175 - looks like that was self deleted though before brig reposted. Guess the original version was posted in the wrong place? I've undeleted it since that seems to make sense here.

Comment: Yeah, now I remember, that is indeed the case. Thanks! Maybe the mechanism should be edited to not take deleted answers into consideration. I would also seem prudent for a moderator who deletes it to do some minimal investigating beforehand, and not rely solely on automatic flagging.

Comment: @mos normally the deleted ones are most interesting because they're people reposting spam, insults and things that just aren't an answer without addressing the issues. I'd guess this was a misclick in a big bunch of similar flags.

Comment: @Flexo ok... what about not considering self-deleted answers, but still considering mod-deleted ones?

Comment: Shouldn't there be "You posted the same answer at [link]. Please review it to edit one of the answers or flag as duplicate" message?

Comment: @bjb there are a few feature requests around that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210373/duplicate-answers-should-be-blocked-rather-than-just-flagged

Comment: @Jan I'd definitely  be up for something smarter, with a caveat that it's a computationally expensive check and "not a problem" duplicated answers are an edge case of an edge case so to some extent investing lots of dev time will have a comparatively low return compared to some other problems.

Comment: I had a lot of windows open yesterday (I open up all the duplicate answer windows and then do deletions/mark the system flags as helpful from another screen). In your case, I thought it was another post, so I deleted it.  Normally I won't have that many open, but we had a number of those because of our backlog.

Comment: @George somehow, it's always Windows fault. ;)