# The status-deferred tag appears to have gotten a new meaning, can it please be explained?

Tags: support, meta, moderator-tags

In the past, the [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) was used to indicate that the bug or request has merit, but won't be done/fixed in the near future, or maybe not at all.

Then staff added the deferred tag to many bugs and requests with a different canned comment, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210373/duplicate-answers-should-be-blocked-rather-than-just-flagged#comment1288978_210373):

> We’ve reviewed this request are moving it to our backlog.

Adding something to a backlog means it will be done at some point - the definition of the other tag [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned). Per the extended tag wiki for [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred):

> A feature request or bug with this tag is something that has been evaluated as positive on potential, but is not present in the current work timeline. **It is not guaranteed to be implemented**, but hasn't been declined either - when it resurfaces, the proposal may be reevaluated and a new decision made depending on how the situation has changed since then.
>
> **Contrast [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), in which a request is something that the site developers have *definitively* approved for implementation but the timing is unknown**

and for [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned):

> A feature request or bug with this tag is something that will be implemented or fixed in an upcoming release in the near future. However, either there is ongoing investigation on the methods to implement the proposal, **there are other active projects that are ahead of it in priority for the site developers**, or the proposal has been implemented in a later build which won't be rolled out to production yet (e.g. due to a weekend or holiday). [...]
>
> Contrast [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), in which the feature is of lower priority and **may be re-evaluated on feasibility at a later date**.

Then again, it was used with the old meaning [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/give-mse-a-way-to-feature-things-on-mse-itself-rather-than-network-wide), only two weeks ago:

> it's unlikely we'll get to this in the near future but we will keep it in mind to improve this

And these days the tag is just added to questions without any comment whatsoever, so it's impossible to know which of those holds true for that request or bug report.

Can this please be officially clarified once and for all? This might also answer [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376736/how-are-status-deferred-and-status-declined-used-by-staff), and let us edit the tag wiki to make it correct.

Comment: "*Adding something to a backlog means it will be done at some point.*" my tech debt backlog would like to have a word.

Comment: *will be done at some point* ... +∞ can be considered as the point

Comment: This is a bit like discovering 'mañana' doesn't actually mean 'tomorrow' it more accurately means 'not today'. ;)

Comment: Wikipedia: [mañana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardiness#Manana).

Comment: Welcome to the world of software engineering. In my company, [tag:status-deferred] roughly means: "yes, it's a valid bug/FR, and we'll get to it once somebody is willing to pay for it". [tag:status-planned] means it's actually in a (current or future) sprint.

Comment: Some [related discussion in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238113/the-product-support-page-in-the-help-center-does-not-make-much-sense-network-w/371684#comment1241712_371684) from 2021: Slate (staff) mentions that the definition of deferred is _items we've actually put on our backlog with a due date of "who knows"_ but that she plans to revisit this definition.

Comment: @Marijn so it's in the back of the backlog. ;)

Comment: @Glorfindel That's as per the general dictionary definitions of the terms. However, based on the extended descriptions of the tags, [tag:status-planned] is also for the former category. [tag:status-deferred] is for things where they haven't made a firm decision to implement but it looks good on first glance.

Comment: @Sonic I don't think "first glance", that would mean they will defer things right away however they review first, hopefully putting time and thought into it, and only then they decide where to send it next.